# CSS - Styling div using classes in same html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown wherein when you click on the parent, it gets displayed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown"></div>
```

To do this I am using jQuery to add a class (`.active`) to the html.

**JS/jQuery**

```
if ($(e).children('.dropdown').hasClass('active')) {
  $(e).children('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
  return;
}
$('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
$(e).children('.dropdown').addClass('active');
return;
```

While writing this, I encountered a problem which could occur.

Having the CSS code look like this:

```
.dropdown{
  /*dropdown styles*/
}

.active{
  /*active styles*/
}
```

Leaves the possibility if I use `.active` for another tag, the two styles could clash.

I quickly learned that

```
.dropdown .active{
  /*active styles*/
}
```

does not work as `.active` is not the child of `.dropdown`

Thus one of the solutions I found was:

```
.parent .active{
  /*active styles*/
}
```

However, if say that `.parent` class has another child which changes styles when clicked (which needs to be styled searately), applying `.active` to it would give the dropdown `.active` styles. If that was a little confusing, see this example:

```
.parent{
  /*parent styles*/
}
.dropdown{
  /*dropdown styles*/
}
.active{
  /*DROPDOWN active styles*/
}
.click-me-button{
  /*default button to be clicked so as to be restyled*/
}
```

(hopefully that makes sense)

I've found two solutions for this:

1) name each `.active` something unique, like `.dropdown-active` and `.click-me-button-active`; however, I am against using this as that requires more typing (call me lazy if you will)

2) use `.dropdown[class="dropdown active"]`; however, this will break if the `<div>` looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown blue active">
```

or

```
<div class="dropdown active blue">
```

To overcome both of this I've found the following:

```
`.dropdown[class*="active"]` or `.dropdown[class~="active"]`
```

they both seem to work the same.

**What I am trying to figure out with this question is: what is correct way to do this and what will be the best preformance-wise choice, of *ANY* of the above**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking to do something like:

```
.dropdown.active {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Note the lack of space between `.dropdown` and `.active`.

Comment: works great and is easier to type than .dropdown[class*="active"]. Thanks!